# Импорт шаблона TWIG в Vue компонент

Tags: vue.js, twig

Имеется компонент, например,

```
<template>
    {{template}}
</template>


<script>
    import cartActions from "../../../../../../templates/components/tooltip-new.twig"


    export default {
      data() {
        return {
        }
      },
      computed: {
        template: function() {
          return cartActions
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        console.log(this.template)
      },
      components: {
        cartActions
      }
    }
```

в консоль выводится: ƒ (context) { return template.render(context); }

Я не совсем уверенна, что его импортировать именно как компонент. Так же пробовала его заинклюдить прямо в template, но в консоль сразу посыпались ошибки

```
<template lang="twig">
    {% include "../../../../../../templates/components/tooltip-new.twig" %}
</template>
```

Uncaught Error: Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined

Нужна именно такая реализация, т.к. на всем проект используется twig и только одна страница написана целиком на Vue. Поэтому требуется импортировать некоторые шаблоны прямо твиговские, но пока не совсем понятно как именно это сделать.

Comment: Twig это же php шаблонизатор, vue с таким не работает и в vue компонентах нельзя использовать то что можно в twig. Попробуйте подключить vue компоненты к twig, почитайте как это лучше делать в symfony.

Answer (score 1):

После долгих попыток у меня получилось найти решение.
Необходимо становить пакет twig-loader, подключить его в webpack.config.

Далее в компоненте создадим вычисляемое свойство:

```
template: function() {
      let max_count = 15;
      let isCart = 1;
      let template = require("путь до файла");
      let html = template({requestUrl: (`/product-view?max_count=${max_count}&isCart=${isCart}`),
        maxCount: max_count,
        isCart: isCart
      });
      return html
    }
```

Далее уже в самом template выведем его через:

```
<div v-html="template"></div>
```

Если кому-то интересно, сам твиговский шаблон выглядел следующим образом:

```
<div {{ selector ?: 'data-static-recommends-ajax-slider' }}
     data-url="{{ requestUrl }}"
     data-max-count="{{ maxCount }}"
     {{ isCart ? 'data-is-cart' : '' }}
     {{ notAvailable ? ' data-not-available' : '' }}>
</div>
```

Все заработало.